# Writing a sortBy function for Dart

Tags: sorting, dart, comparable

I'm trying to write a utility function that sorts a list by a given property:

```
List<T> sortBy<T, U extends Comparable<U>>(List<T> items, U Function(T item) f) =>
    items.toList()..sort((item1, item2) => f(item1).compareTo(f(item2)));
```

I've run into a problem when the property is an int, e.g.

```
sortBy<String, int>(['apple', 'ball', 'cow'], (word) => word.length);
```

I get a compilation error:

```
error: 'int' doesn't extend 'Comparable<int>'.
```

Why is `int` not `Comparable`? Is there another way to write `sortBy` so that it works on `int` as well as `Comparable`'s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

int does implement `Comparable` but implements `Comparable<num>` which is your issue since you want to check for `Comparable<int>`. Could you not just define sortBy like this?

```
List<T> sortBy<T, U extends Comparable>(List<T> items, U Function(T item) f) =>
    items.toList()..sort((item1, item2) => f(item1).compareTo(f(item2)));
```

This seems to work since we now just want to ensure U extends `Comparable`.